# How to stop IE7 clearing floats because of hasLayout

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-float, haslayout

I have a containing element with a number of floated elements in it. That containing element also has a percentage width value applied to it.

In IE7, content following the element containing the floats is cleared because of the width value which gives it hasLayout (I think!).

I don't want the containing element to haveLayout, but I do need it to have an explicit width. Is there a way of working around this problem in IE7, effectively forcing hasLayout=false.

Comment: Or any other way to prevent it from clearing I suppose? I am having the same problem but had no luck finding a solution so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix some haslayout rendering problems using:

```
* {
 zoom: 1.0;
}
```

Good luck.

Comment: Yeah, it's the opposite I want. And no, zoom:0, won't do it. :)

I'll try and come up with a simple test-case that I can link to to make this more clear.

Comment: Yeah, I've always read there's no way to reverse haslayout--you can force haslayout and some situations trigger haslayout naturally, but once an element haslayout, it can't be taken away...be interested to see what you come up with.